# Merging files so row in Table 1 is repeated for each row in Table 2

Tags: shell, unix, join, awk, sed

Not sure what the technicial term for this join of two tables is (have spent ages on google).
In SQL you'd write it
Select * from table1, table2;

i have Table 1

```
Var1
1
2
3
```

& Table 2

```
Var2
6
7
8
```

i want to merge/join so i have

```
Var1 Var2
1  6
1  7
1  8
2  6
2  7
2  8
3  6
3  7
3  8
```

(i..e, each var1 is repeated for each var2)
Other than writing a loop is there a short way to do this like I do in SQL?

Comment: This is called Cartesian product. What language do you try to implement it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using awk would be like

```
awk 'FNR==NR{line[$0]++; next} {for (i in line) print $1, i} ' file2 file1
```

**Test**

```
$ cat file1
1
2
3

$ cat file2
6
7
8
$ awk 'FNR==NR{line[$0]++; next} {for (i in line) print $1, i} ' file2 file1
1 6
1 7
1 8
2 6
2 7
2 8
3 6
3 7
3 8
```

Comment: That `in` loop will output the contents of `file2` in the order they are stored internally in a hash table, not necessarily the order they appeared in file2. It also won't handle the header line.

Answer (score 2):

No, best you can hope for is:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} FNR==1{print $0, a[1]; next} {for (i=2;i in a;i++) print $0, a[i]}' file2 file1
Var1 Var2
1 6
1 7
1 8
2 6
2 7
2 8
3 6
3 7
3 8
```

The input files were:

```
$ cat file1
Var1
1
2
3
$ cat file2
Var2
6
7
8
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first file is small enough to fit in memory, you can do

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '# Pesky header line
    FNR==1 { if (NR==1) h=$0; else print h, $0; next }
    NR==FNR { a[++i] = $0; next }
    { for (j=1; j<=i; ++j) print a[j], $0 }' table1 table2
```

For really big or really small files, maybe try

```
sed 1d table1 |
while read -r line; do
    sed "1d;s/^/$line\t/" table2
done >outputfile
```

(This will just discard the first line because I'm lazy. Not having header lines would simplify things.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting way of accomplishing it with GNU parallel and Bash. I assume no headers as that simplifies the problem (see below for one way of handling headers).

#### Without headers

First we generate the test input:

```
cat << End-of-table1 > file1
1
2
3
End-of-table1

cat << End-of-table2 > file2
6
7
8
End-of-table2
```

Now run `parallel` with the files as input arguments:

```
parallel echo {1} {2} :::: file1 :::: file2
```

This results in:

```
1 6
1 7
1 8
2 6
2 7
2 8
3 6
3 7
3 8
```

#### With headers

To handle headers and tab delimit the columns the solution below produces the correct result based on the given test data.

First produce test-data with a header:

```
cat << End-of-table1 > file1
Var1
1
2
3
End-of-table1

cat << End-of-table2 > file2
Var2
6
7
8
End-of-table2
```

Extract the headers with `head` and `paste` and then use `parallel` again to combine the columns without headers:

```
paste <(head -n1 file1) <(head -n1 file2); parallel printf '"%s\t%s\n"' {1} {2} \
                                             :::: <(tail -n+2 file1)            \
                                             :::: <(tail -n+2 file2)
```

Output:

```
Var1    Var2
1   6
1   7
1   8
2   6
2   7
2   8
3   6
3   7
3   8
```

#### Pertinent parts of the GNU parallel manual

```
parallel [options] [command [arguments]] ( ::: arguments | :::: argfile(s) ) ...

...

::: arguments
         Use arguments from the command line as input source instead of stdin
         (standard input). Unlike other options for GNU parallel ::: is
         placed after the command and before the arguments.

...

         If multiple ::: are given, each group will be treated as an input
         source, and all combinations of input sources will be generated.
         E.g. ::: 1 2 ::: a b c will result in the combinations (1,a) (1,b)
         (1,c) (2,a) (2,b) (2,c). This is useful for replacing nested for-
         loops.

...

:::: argfiles
         Another way to write -a argfile1 -a argfile2 ...

         ::: and :::: can be mixed.

             See -a, ::: and --xapply.
```